# How laravel manages multiple union in DB Query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have 3 Union Query in my Laravel, the query works in SQL but in Laravel it won't. and displays this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'union all
```

here is the code look like.

```
$android = DB::connection("mysql2")->table('android')
     ->join('game_players', 'game_players.id', '=', 'android.playerId')
     ->select("android.playerId", "android.dateAdded", "android.identifier")
     ...
     ->where("android.dateAdded", "<>", '');

$ios = DB::connection("mysql2")->table('ios')
     ->join('game_players', 'game_players.id', '=', 'ios.playerId')
     ->select("ios.playerId", "ios.dateAdded", "ios.identifier")
     ...
     ->unionAll($android);

$steam = DB::connection("mysql2")->table(steam')
     ->join('game_players', 'game_players.id', '=', 'steam.playerId')
     ->select("playerId", "dateAdded", "identifier")
     ...
     ->unionAll($ios)
     ->get();
```

I really don't have any idea what causes this error but maybe because of I called union in 3 times? any idea about this one?

Union works if it is only two but when I added the third one, it got the error

Answer (score 0):

my mistakes.. this is the answer:

```
$android = DB::connection("mysql2")->table('android')
     ->join('game_players', 'game_players.id', '=', 'android.playerId')
     ->select("android.playerId", "android.dateAdded", "android.identifier")
     ...
     ->where("android.dateAdded", "<>", '');

$ios = DB::connection("mysql2")->table('ios')
     ->join('game_players', 'game_players.id', '=', 'ios.playerId')
     ->select("ios.playerId", "ios.dateAdded", "ios.identifier")
     ...


$steam = DB::connection("mysql2")->table(steam')
     ->join('game_players', 'game_players.id', '=', 'steam.playerId')
     ->select("playerId", "dateAdded", "identifier")
     ...
     ->union($ios)
    ->union($android);
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to use eloquent model’s relationships instead of DB.